# A symbol occurs in more than one context:one of the definitions is shadowed

Tags: packages, contexts

I started *Mathematica 10* and run as the tutorial says:

```
trainingset = {1 -> "A", 2 -> "A", 3.5 -> "B", 4 -> "B"};
c = Classify[trainingset]
```

but the outut is :

> ```
> Classify[{1 -> "A", 2 -> "A", 3.5 -> "B", 4 -> "B"}]
> ```

which is not expected.

System: *Windows 7, x64*

`$Packages` gives:

> ```
> {"QuantityUnit`", "HTTPClient`", "HTTPClient`OAuth`", 
>  "HTTPClient`CURLInfo`", "HTTPClient`CURLLink`", "Utilities`URLTools`", "JLink`", 
>  "WolframAlphaClient`", "GetFEKernelInit`", "ResourceLocator`", "PacletManager`", 
>  "System`", "Global`"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.

1. If I start *Mathematica 10* and immediately run

   ```
   Context["Classify"]
   ```

   it will says

   > Context::notfound: Symbol Classify not found

   and if I run

   ```
   Context[Classify]
   ```

   **note: without quote.** *Mathematica* will tell you:

   > "Global`"
2. But When I run

   ```
   Needs["MachineLearning`"]
   ```

   and then run

   ```
   Context["Classify"]
   ```

   *Mathematica* gives

   > System`

   It seems wired that it is not in the `MachineLearning` package.

Comment: Not weird, just not loaded, so on initial parse, it shows up as part of ``Global` ``. As to why it didn't load when you executed the example is very curious.